# php ftp connection - close at the end of the script? I want a persistent connection?

Tags: php, ftp, persistent

it looks php closes FTP connection at the end of the executed script, just like with database connection, how to create persistent connection?

Comment: I want to do a little client, and not to connect/disconnect everytime. To get speed and dont overload the server. Got it? :)

Comment: php is a poor choice of language to use to create an ftp client.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474577/persist-an-ftp-connection-php-resource-across-ajax-calls and http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftphp/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible now. There is already request ticket opened though, look [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9969&edit=2)

Comment: wouldn't hold your breath for this to get implemented as the ticket has been open since 2001

Comment: @Phill I know. But I had to link that, just to see that he isn't the first wanting this feature

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried digging into the [PHP FTP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) ??